# 2005 SQL Reporting Services Dataset filter with OR not AND

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Under Dataset Filters Tab, I want to use OR not AND but when I add a second Filter the AND appears in the And/Or column with no way to change it.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is that each row is anded with the next. To acheive an or expression you have to put it in the same like

```
line 1 -> =Fields!One.Value = 10 OR Fields!Two.Value |  =  |  =True
line 2 -> =Fields!Three.Value                        |  =  | ="some other value"
```

There could be other ways of doing it, but I found this to be consistent and easy to understand.